# Link to route while keeping user input

Tags: jquery-mobile, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have made an app with jQuery mobile and laravel.

On the first page "mobilepage1" if have a form with a next button.

Also some of the form elements are dropdown menu's. The dropdown select options I get from a table in the database.

In the form on mobilepage1 I have a dropdown list with all department names:
I get this list from my controller like so:

```
$departmentlist = Company::find($usercompanyid)->departments;
```

This is how I display the list in the mobilepage1 form:

```
{{ Form::label('department', 'Department:')}}
<?php
      foreach($afdelingslijst as $item) {
          $afdelingsarray[$item->afdelingen] = $item->afdelingen;
      }        
?>

{{Form::select('size',$afdelingsarray)}}
```

On the second page I want to make a back button.

I tried the jQuery mobile way with a link with: data-rel="back"

But this does not work. I get a page error, it's missing the departmentlist used in mobilepage1. I can make a link to a route to mobilepage1, but I think all the information the user entered in mobilepage1 would be gone.

I see this url in the address bar when I am on mobilepage2 (this is after I filled in the form on mobilepage1 and clicked next).

```
/public/mobilepage2?size=Personeelszaken&size=32&directechef=Tineke&size=1&size=1&size=1&date-2=&size=1&time=&omschrijving=
```

Is there a way I can link to the the mobilepage1 route and still keep the information the user entered?

Comment: Which method are you using to open the form?  `open` or `model`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it would work just by hitting the back button if you passed in the `department` list with a view composer rather than through a route.  Remove it from your route and place this in a file that's being autoloaded...

```
View::composer('mobilepage2', function($view)
{
    $departmentlist = Company::find($usercompanyid)->departments()->lists('afdelingen','afdelingen');
    $view->with('departmentlist', $departmentlist);
});
```

I'm not sure how you are finding `$usercompanyid` but you should be able to find it within the closure or pass it in by adding `use ($usercompanyid)` right after the `function($view)` part.

Also using the `lists()` function like that will build your array for you so you don't need to worry about the foreach loop in your view.

Since the values are getting passed back and forth as get variables, I think if you use `Form::model()` instead of `Form::open()`, it should place all those values back into the input fields for you.